# Check if a string contains characters

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a pattern which 
must accepts every input but it 
should **NOT** accept ONLY numbers or ONLY special characters.

I need to create that pattern in the html5 pattern tag.

Example :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern3

Comment: So what are valid and invalid examples?

Comment: i mean this should be valid : name123><.,,

Comment: this should also be valid : name123

Comment: this should be valid : name...,/

Comment: this would be invalid : 123

Comment: this would be invalid : .,./,>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for your specified test cases, anyway.

```
pattern="(?=.*\D)(?=.*[0-9A-Za-z]).*"
```